# Can you convert UrlFetchApp into a promise in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, promise, urlfetch

UrlFetchApp.fetch executes synchronously and makes execution slow. Is it possible to convert UrlFetchApp into promise?

I have been thinking of this approach:

1. Return `HTTPResponse.getContent()` as a Promise and add all the urls into a queue.
2. Defer their execution till `getContent().then()` is invoked.
3. When `getContent()` of any of the urls is called, use `fetchAll` to get all
   results and clear the queue.

Do you see any problems with this approach?

Comment: Some users think all questions should have code and should be a debugging question. That should/would probably be a reason for downvotes and/or question close.

Comment: Thanks! The question is literally about execution stack and assumed it fits Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I think it fits. But others  seem to disagree. I'm just  making a  experienced guess on the probable cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, The approach seems sound, especially since it's known that [`.fetchAll` executes asynchronously](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c0f383034045ab63c19604139ecb0728).

- `.fetch()` call is where the actual fetch happens. So any hook into the UrlFetchApp object should be inserted before the `fetch` call is made.
- You may employ a [`Proxy object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to hook into `.fetch` calls on `UrlFetchApp` to return a dummy `HTTPResponse` with a `thenable` object
- Then use `fetchAll` on `.getContent`  call as stated in the question.
- Note however that promises in apps script may or may not execute asynchronously as stated in the [issue comments #1 to #4](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149937257). This however shouldn't be a issue with your approach.

Given the finicky nature and unclear documentation on promises, It's better to avoid them in any production environment. A better way to achieve batching requests is to use plain custom functions with a `thenable` object:

```
function test() {
  /**
   * @description Batches requests until then is called on a response
   *   and fetches all batched requests
   * @return {object} A then object, which when called fetches the batch
   * @param {string} url Url to fetch
   * @param {object} options Options to fetch. See UrlFetchApp.fetch
   */
  const fetchAsBatch = function fetch(requests, url, options) {
    options.url = url;
    requests.add(options);
    return {
      then: func => {
        const responses = func(UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([...requests]));
        requests.clear();// clear current batch
        return responses;
      },
    };
  }.bind(this, new Set());

  const successHandlerLogger = responses => {
    /*Do something with all responses*/
    console.log(responses.map(response => response.getContentText()));
  };
  fetchAsBatch('https://example.com', { method: 'get' });
  fetchAsBatch('https://httpbin.org/post', { method: 'post' }).then(
    successHandlerLogger
  );
  fetchAsBatch('https://google.com', {}).then(successHandlerLogger);
}
```

```js
function test() {
  /**
   * @description Batches requests until then is called on a response
   *   and fetches all batched requests
   * @return {object} A then object, which when called fetches the batch
   * @param {string} url Url to fetch
   * @param {object} options Options to fetch. See UrlFetchApp.fetch
   */
  const fetchAsBatch = function fetch(requests, url, options) {
    options.url = url;
    requests.add(options);
    return {
      then: func => {
        const responses = func(UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([...requests]));
        requests.clear();
        return responses;
      },
    };
  }.bind(this, new Set());

  const successHandlerLogger = responses => {
    /*Do something with all responses*/
    console.log(responses.map(response => response.getContentText()));
  };
  fetchAsBatch('https://example.com', { method: 'get' });
  fetchAsBatch('https://httpbin.org/post', { method: 'post' }).then(
    successHandlerLogger
  );
  fetchAsBatch('https://google.com', {}).then(successHandlerLogger);
}
/*Mock urlfetchapp library to return requests without fetch*/
const UrlFetchApp = {
  fetchAll: requests =>
    requests.map(request => ({
      getContentText: () => request,
    })),
};

test();
```

Comment: This is great! I am planning to use this in Google Workspace addon which expects to return builder.build(). Can I return the above promise proxy instead, which resolves into builder.build()?

Comment: @Queen'sGambit  It's better to avoid unstable features like promises in a add-on unless absolutely necessary. In your case, How about just  using a custom function? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thenable is a wonderful idea. Thanks for the code. I will try it out.